# If a smooth map between manifolds is injective, is the induced map on the tangent spaces injective too?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

If $\phi:M\longrightarrow N$ is an injective smooth map between two manifolds, then is $d\phi_m:M_m\longrightarrow N_{\phi(m)}$, the induced map between the tangent spaces injective too?

I tried the following : If $v\in M_m$ is such that $d\phi_m(v)=0$, then for all $g$, $C^{\infty}$ function in a neighbourhood of $\phi(m)$, $d\phi_m(v)(g)=0$, that is $v(g\circ\phi)=0$ for all such $g$. From this can we conclude that $v$ is the $0$ tangent vector.

I got this doubt when I was trying to understand the definition of an immersion. I was wondering if $\phi$ being injective will automatically make it an immersion.

Comment: If it helps future readers, [Tu says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAsBN.png) the prototype of an immersion is the inclusion map, which is both an immersion and injective. So I guess this particular injective map being the prototype of immersions is what may lead people to think that injective maps are immersions or that immersions are injective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $\phi:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ be $\phi(t)=(t^3,t^9)$. Then the derivative at $t=0$ is not injective.

Comment: You can also use the function $f(x)=x^3$ from the real line to itself.

Comment: probably the best example.

Answer (score 0):

If the map $\phi:M\longrightarrow N$ is an diffeomorphism then $d\phi_m:M_m\longrightarrow N_{\phi(m)}$ is an isomorphism.